# javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract date month and year (if present) from a string through regular expressions in JS. My input string can be like "I go home on April 13 " or "I go home on 13th April" or " on 31st August 2015 , I go home" , In all the cases I want to extract month date and Year so that later I can change it format like DD/MM/YYYY . if year is not present I would take present year.

I tried with regex :

```
> var reg =
> /\b(?:(?:jan|feb)?r?(?:uary)?|mar(?:ch)?|apr(?:il)?|may|june?|july?|aug(?:ust)?|oct(?:ober)?|(?:sept?|nov|dec)(?:ember)?)\s+\d{1,2}/ig
```

but it matches only April 13 , how can I match 13th April or 13 April , and also split month and date so that I can later convert it to format DD/MM/YYYY.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/f1dc9yck/4/) is the fiddle .
Thanks

Comment: people who downvoted  questions , kindly let me know the answer if you can help , then there is no need to downvote , I have done research on this and fiddle you can see , one case I was able to get . Its v easy to down vote and move on . People post on stackoverflow when they dont get solutions

Comment: dont downvote being anonymous , first leave comment here and explain me why its wrong question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this regex works :

```
/\b\s*(\d*)\s*(?:st|th|nd)*\s* (?:(?:jan|feb)?r?(?:uary)?|mar(?:ch)?|apr(?:il)?|may|june?|july?|aug(?:ust)?|oct(?:ober)?|(?:sept?|nov|dec)(?:ember)?)\s*(\d*)(?:st|th|nd)*\s* (\d*)/ig
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/f1dc9yck/125/) is fiddle

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse these strings I suggest keeping the regular expression simpler and add some logic in the code. This will keep it easy.

Basically what you want to match is either `(month) (day)` or `(day)(st|th) (month)` followed by a optional `(year)`.

This becomes:

```
((month) (day))|((day)(st|th) (month)( )?(year)?)
```

Now substitute `[0-9]+` for day and year, and finally `[a-zA-Z]+` for month to keep it simple.

```
(([a-zA-Z]+) ([0-9]+))|(([0-9]+)(st|th) ([a-zA-Z]+)( )?([0-9]+)?)
```

This also matches either `st` or `th` and a possible space before the year. So by making that non-capturing by applying a non-capturing group operator `(?: )`, it becomes:

```
(([a-zA-Z]+) ([0-9]+))|(([0-9]+)(?:st|th) ([a-zA-Z]+)(?: )?([0-9]+)?)
```

---

```
var re = /(([a-zA-Z]+) ([0-9]+))|(([0-9]+)(?:st|th) ([a-zA-Z]+)(?: )?([0-9]+)?)/; 
var str = '31st August 2015';
var matches;

if ((matches = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (matches .index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }

    console.log(matches);
    // Use matches[i] to access the matches
}
```

Comment: hello Tim , my input string can contain anything like " My flight is on dec 3" or  "I applied leave for 4th dec"  or " on 3 dec I am on leave" . So I need to match if its valid month { dec/december} then gets its date from suffix and prefix from month name . I have attached fiddle above where I am able to match April 13

Comment: @Bhupendra That's actually what I meant by *logic in code*. Since involving that in a regular expression will easily make it hard to maintain. You could get the month from the matches and process that with some JavaScript or maybe another regular expression like: `(Jan|Feb|Etc)|(January|February|Etcetc)` with the case insensitive modifier.